# is sparing-batch processing support for images?

Tags: spring-batch

How to load multiple images to DB using Spring Batch processing?

```
<step id="step1">
<tasklet reader="flatFileItemReader"
writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="10"
skip-limit="10">
29 Spring Batch 2.0 © 2009
<skippable-exception-classes>
java.lang.Exception
</skippable-exception-classes>
<fatal-exception-classes>
java.io.FileNotFoundException
</fatal-exception-classes>
</tasklet>
</job>
-----------
----------
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and make a  minimal, complete, and verifiable example

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.